# Can you use AngularJS in a php file?

Tags: php, html, angularjs, web

I would like to use AngularJS in a php file so that i can include other php files
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: So that you can include other php files? Why would you want to use angular for this?  Can't you just use php?

Comment: I think you need to do some research on what AngularJS is and how it works. It is a frontend framework, the only way it can interact with PHP is through AJAX requests.

Comment: What's wrong with `http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php`?, unless you want to do some sort of AJAX stuff.

Comment: You can use AngularJS in a PHP site, sure. But, surely you should include .php fragments using PHP. Maybe if you expand a bit on what problem you're trying to solve in the first place, we can offer suggestions?

Comment: Angular is Clientside JS Framework executed on browser and PHP is serverside scripting language executed at server. They can't directly interact with each other.

Comment: @EliteCake Update your question to include any additional code, do not put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular JS is a javascript framework, this means it's a client side executed scipt.
PHP a server side executed script.
The answear is NO you cannot include php file using angular js, as angular is a client side executed script and including PHP file requires server side executed script.